Will I mix Dutch with German up?
I speak German at C1 and I want to learn Dutch. Will I mix these two languages ​​when I use them all the time and my Dutch is at an advanced level with German? And if I learn Dutch and devote more time to it, will my German get worse (which I don't want)?

Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Your question looks like a variation on Can learning L3 interfere with my grammatical knowledge of L2?. Could you please check whether your question is answered there?

[correction: mix German up with Dutch OR mix up A and B. It seems to me that each learner will have a different experience with languages that are close to each other.

This question can only be based on opinions.

It most probably won't degrade your language skills and you won't mix them up.
Our brain is remarkably adapt in learning things and also connecting those experiences with the circumstances they appeared in ("context dependent memory or learning").
Generally speaking, learning new things, especially new languages (because our brain is a "language-driven-machine") will enhance your neuro-plasticity - the forming of new synapse pathways, enhancing the storing and recalling of memories.
You might encounter situations in which you "search" for a certain vocabulary which you know in Dutch but need it in German or vice versa. This will not turn out to be detrimental. You will either be able to draw from the second language to find vocabulary quick or you are in a situation were it does not matter if you mix up a single word (while reading or speaking) or even ask for help finding the right word (in everyday-speech with other people).
It is like riding a bicycle - you won't forget it and your skills won't degrade just by learning how to drive a car for example. Also think of people who are easily being able to learn seven languages or more. Don't be afraid to learn new things!
